# Intercambiar un botón

Tags: javafx

Tengo un panel tipo *VBox* con dos botones, A y B.
Al cargar la App sólo se ve A, si se pulsa, se oculta y aparece B. Pulsando B, este se oculta y aparece A... Y así sucesivamente, solo aparece o A o B en la interfaz, nunca ambos simultáneamente.

Esto lo estoy controlando con **setVisible()** a *true* o *false*. Problema:
aunque un botón no se vea ocupa un espacio en la interfaz. Con lo que A se vera siempre en una posición y B siempre en otra bajo la que ocupaba el primero. Lo que necesito es que se sitúen en el mismo lugar.

Código de la clase que gestiona los eventos:

```
package app.view;

//imports
import javafx.scene.control.*;

class Events {

    /**********************************/
    /*** Properties declaration *******/

        private boolean is_running  = false;
        private Button btn_a        = null;
        private Button btn_b        = null;


    /**********************************/
    /*** Methods declaration **********/

        /**
         * Constructor
         * 
         * @param   btn_a
         * @param   btn_b
         */
        public Events( 
            Button btn_a,
            Button btn_b
        ) {
            this.btn_a  = btn_a;
            this.btn_b = btn_b;

            btn_a.setOnAction( e -> {
                this.pushA();
            });

            btn_b.setOnAction( e -> {
                this.pushB();
            });
        }


        /**
         * Runs the counter
         * 
         */
        private void pushA() {
            System.out.println( "Events / pushA()" );

            this.is_running = true;

            this.btn_a.setVisible( false );
            this.btn_b.setVisible( true );

            swapBtns();
        }

        /**
         * Stops the counter
         * 
         */
        private void pushB() {
            System.out.println( "Events / pushB()" );

            this.is_running = false;

            this.btn_a.setVisible( true );
            this.btn_b.setVisible( false );

            swapBtns();
        }

        private void swapBtns() {
            System.out.println( "Events / swapBtns()" );

            double b1x = btn_a.getLayoutX();
            double b1y = btn_a.getLayoutY();
            double b2x = btn_b.getLayoutX();
            double b2y = btn_b.getLayoutY();
            System.out.println( "Pos btn_a x: " + b1x );
            System.out.println( "Pos btn_a y: " + b1y );
            System.out.println( "Pos btn_b x: " + b2x );
            System.out.println( "Pos btn_b y: " + b2y );

            if ( is_running ) {
                this.btn_a.setLayoutX( b2x );
                this.btn_a.setLayoutY( b2y );
                this.btn_b.setLayoutX( b1x );
                this.btn_b.setLayoutY( b1y );

            } else {
                this.btn_a.setLayoutX( b1x );
                this.btn_a.setLayoutY( b1y );
                this.btn_b.setLayoutX( b2x );
                this.btn_b.setLayoutY( b2y );
            }
        }

} //class
```

El método que no me esta funcionando es **swapBtns()**, donde he probado a intercambiar las coordenadas de cada botón con el otro. Se me ocurre tener sólo un botón y gestionar el contenido textual del mismo así como los eventos con la propiedad **is_running**, pero preferiría poder tener los dos botones.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre una solución a mi problema

***Primero:***

**Para que ambos botones ocupen la misma posición** (sólo uno es visible) se puede usar un layout de tipo **StackPane**. Los botones se meten en este layout y este a su vez en el que originalmente contenía los botones, en este caso un **VBox**. Si en lugar de un *StackPane* creo otro *VBox* en su lugar, sigo teniendo el mismo problema, lo que relaciono tango con el tipo de contenedor como con la composición de mi GUI (no encontré la causa concreta).

***Segundo:***

**swapBtns()** que no funcionaba, se elimina. Basta con alternar la visibilidad en los botones, una vez que se pueden situar en la posición requerida.

***Ejemplos:***

Clase de ejemplo con ambos botones ocupando la misma posición usando un StackPane:

```
package pruebasjavafx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DosBotones extends Application {

    /**********************************************
     * Properties
     */
        private boolean is_running = false;

        private Button btn_a = new Button( "Botón A" );
        private Button btn_b = new Button( "Botón B" );


    /**********************************************
     * Public methods
     */

        @Override
        public void start( Stage primaryStage ) {

            StackPane root = new StackPane();
            root.getChildren().add( btn_a );
            root.getChildren().add( btn_b );
            setEvents();
            configButtons();

            btn_a.setVisible( true );
            btn_b.setVisible( false );

            Scene scene = new Scene( root, 300, 250 );

            primaryStage.setTitle( "Hello World!" );
            primaryStage.setScene( scene );
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

    /**********************************************
     * Private methods
     */
        private void configButtons() {
            this.btn_a.setPrefSize( 180, 56 );  //Button size
            this.btn_b.setPrefSize( 180, 56 );
    }

        private void setEvents() {

            this.btn_a.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle( ActionEvent event ) {
                    System.out.println( "Pulsado botón A" );

                    is_running = true;
                    swapBtns();
                }
            });

            this.btn_b.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle( ActionEvent event ) {
                    System.out.println( "Pulsado botón B" );

                    is_running = false;
                    swapBtns();
                }
            });
        }

        private void swapBtns() {

            if ( is_running ) {
                this.btn_a.setVisible( false );
                this.btn_b.setVisible( true );
            } else {
                this.btn_a.setVisible( true );
                this.btn_b.setVisible( false );
            }
        }

} //class
```

Clase de ejemplo con ambos botones ocupando la misma posición usando un VBox:

```
package pruebasjavafx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author orici
 */
public class DosBotones2 extends Application {

    /**********************************************
     * Properties
     */

        private boolean is_running = false;
        private Button btn_a = new Button( "Botón A" );
        private Button btn_b = new Button( "Botón B" );


    /**********************************************
     * Public methods
     */

        @Override
        public void start( Stage primaryStage ) {

            VBox root = new VBox();
            root.getChildren().add( btn_a );
            root.getChildren().add( btn_b );
            configPanel( root );

            setEvents();
            configButtons();

            Scene scene = new Scene( root, 300, 250 );
            primaryStage.setTitle( "Hello World!" );
            primaryStage.setScene( scene );
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

    /**********************************************
     * Private methods
     */

        private void configButtons() {
            this.btn_a.setPrefSize( 180, 56 );  //Button size
            this.btn_b.setPrefSize( 180, 56 );

            btn_a.setVisible( true );
            btn_b.setVisible( false );
    }

        private void configPanel( VBox root ) {
            root.setAlignment( Pos.CENTER );
            root.setPadding( new Insets( 10, 10, 10, 10 ));
            root.setSpacing( 8 ); //Vertical spacing between the nodes
        }

        private void setEvents() {

            this.btn_a.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle( ActionEvent event ) {
                    System.out.println( "Pulsado botón A" );

                    is_running = true;
                    btn_a.setVisible( false );
                    btn_b.setVisible( true );
                }
            });

            this.btn_b.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle( ActionEvent event ) {
                    System.out.println( "Pulsado botón B" );

                    is_running = false;
                    btn_a.setVisible( true );
                    btn_b.setVisible( false );
                }
            });
        }

} //class
```

Answer (score 0):

En Scene Builder colocas tus 2 botones uno arriba del otro, y desactivas el que sera el segundo, con el mismo tamaño para que no se vea el que esta atras, y harias el intercambio asi:

```
@FXML
private void btn2A(ActionEvent event) {
    btn2.toBack();
    btn.setDisable(false);
    btn2.setDisable(true);
}
@FXML
private void btnA(ActionEvent event) {
    btn.toBack();
    btn.setDisable(true);
    btn2.setDisable(false);
}
```

Estamos haciendo que cada boton se mande hacia el fondo, y se desactive, y active el otro boton para asi evitar problemas en caso de que el boton de abajo llagase a ser presionado de alguna forma

Comment: Esto no me funciona. Me pasa lo mismo en cuanto a las posiciones de los botones de esta forma, solo que el botón "desavilitado" si es visible.

Comment: Mira en teoria seguira siendo visible, por eso es mejor que tengan el mismo tamaño tanto de altura como de largo, pero igual puedes hacer que al desactivarlos tambien los hagas invisibles,debe funcionar, solo no le coloques una posicion,  y no los metas dentro de un vbox o hbox, tu colocalo donde deseas que se muestren los dos @Orici